# Sorry Ubuntu 22.04 had Experienced an internal Error

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

After every reboot, Ubuntu give me this error "Sorry Ubuntu 22.04 had Experienced an internal Error". In the details there is next data:

ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Package: bluez 5.64-0ubuntu1

Title: bluetoothd assert failure: malloc_consolidate(): unaligned fastbin chunk detected

And many more data.

In syslog I found this, I think it might be helpful:
*unknown attribute /module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm

I have a Bluetooth adapter, but I have unplugged it after it have troubles connecting to Xbox controller. Right before the problem with connection appeared "apport-gtk" was loading my CPU. Because of that I googled and according to one guide executed this command "rm /var/crash/*". I guess this might be a problem.

If I can provide any more data, let me know!

Is there any way to fix this problem without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused by a variety of factors, and there are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve it.

First, you can try disabling the Bluetooth daemon (bluetoothd) on your system. This is the process that manages the Bluetooth adapter and handles communication with Bluetooth devices. If the Bluetooth daemon is not functioning properly, it can cause issues with other programs that use Bluetooth, including the error message you're seeing. To disable the Bluetooth daemon, follow these steps:

Open a terminal and run the following command to stop the Bluetooth daemon:

```
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
```

Next, run the following command to disable the Bluetooth daemon so that it does not start automatically on boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth
```

Reboot your system and see if the error message persists.
If disabling the Bluetooth daemon does not resolve the issue, you can try removing the Bluetooth package (bluez) from your system and then reinstalling it. This will remove any corrupted files or configuration settings that may be causing the issue, and then replace them with fresh copies. To do this, follow these steps:

Open a terminal and run the following command to remove the Bluetooth package:

```
sudo apt remove bluez
```

Once the package has been removed, run the following command to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install bluez
```

Reboot your system and see if the error message persists.
If the issue still persists after trying these steps, you may need to try a more comprehensive troubleshooting approach, such as resetting your system's Bluetooth configuration files or manually uninstalling and reinstalling the Bluetooth package.